# Binding Issue with custom control inside a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, binding, richtextbox

I'm totally stumped by this one.

Here's the setup:

RichTextBox that has your standard runs, and paragraphs. When user selects some text, hits a hotkey, I replace the selected text with a custom control derived from InlineUIContainer - let's call it CustomContainer.

CustomContainer has a single child of type TextBlock. TextBlock's TextProperty is bound to an object whose property changes.

This was done so that the text of this property cannot be edited - if you select it, or try to delete it, it deletes the entire chunk rather than any characters.

All this works beautifully.

Here's the problem:

When you click Save we take the entire RichTextBox data, serialize it, and save it to a text file. When you then reopen the file, all the bindings are re-wired as needed, and everything looks as it should.

Until the property that's bound to is changed.

At this point CustomContainer does not change. Remember, CustomContainer has a TextBlock with the Text property bound. If I look at the TextBlock in question, I can see the Text property has changed - *however,* visually nothing has changed. I've tried doing various things to refresh the container, but nothing seems to work. I've tried UpdateLayout, I've tried changing the binding, but nothing does the trick.

If I go and delete that CustomContainer from the RichTextBox and then highlight and hit the hot-key everything works. So the code and the binding works. Somewhere in the deserialization, rebinding, and updating of the RichTextBox, the painting of the property as it changes stops working...

UPDATE: I've managed to get it working, though I consider it a bit of a hack. I'm going to keep it open in case someone can provide me with a real solution.

What I've done is removed the custom control on load, and create a new one from scratch and insert at the same position. This is doing the trick, though I'm confused as to why (it only amounted to just calling the constructor, removing the old and adding the new. The rest of the code with the binding is all the same, so I'm still confused why this would work - or rather, why the other way doesn't)

Comment: Are you using INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes. I've given that a shot, and it doesn't work. Keep in mind, if it was related to this, it likely wouldn't work when it's not by highlighting and hitting the hot key.